# Assembly plugin assembling module dependencies not full project dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Basically I have a multi-module project with this structure and dependencies

```
pom - With dependencies with scope provided
  + ---- mod1 - with mod1 dependencies
          + -----  depends on libAAA
          + ------ depends on libBBB
  + ---- mod2 - with mod2 dependencies
          + -----  depends on libXXX
          + ------ depends on libYYY
```

Assembly (using maven-assembly-plugin) is expected to look like this:

```
bin/lib      - Contains all provided dependencies
bin/mod1/    - Contains mod1 artifact
bin/mod1/lib - Contains mod1 dependencies (only mod1) 
bin/mod2/    - Contains mod2 artifact
bin/mod2/lib - Contains mod2 dependencies (only mod2)
```

Everything works "almost" as expected, but ALL PROJECT dependencies
are copied to mod1/lib and mod2/lib so the resulting assembly looks this way

```
bin/mod1/lib
bin/mod2/lib
   BOTH containing libAAA, libBBB, libXXX, libYYY
```

What I'm expecting to obtain is this:

```
bin/mod1/lib
    containing libAAA, libBBB
bin/mod2/lib
    containing libXXX, libYYY
```

Does someone knows if its possible to just copy "isolated" (not sure what word to use) module dependencies on each of these directories without using filters ?

thanks in advance, 
tonio

Comment: assembly.xml is quite simple, but if someone needs to see it, I'll add it without any trouble.

Comment: I really think it is necessary to show us the assembly.xml. I need to know how you have set it up. And where are you using the `maven-assembly-plugin`? Is it in the top pom or in each child?

Comment: Added assembly descriptor and pom's configuration as an answer to this question, thanks maba

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding the assembly descriptor.

This descriptor is set in a "pom" module called distribution, as described
in maven-assembly-plugin docs for multi-module projects.

I tried generating 2 moduleSet instead of just one, 
one for each module and the result is the same as described above.

Here goes the XML & pom configuration:

---

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
        <id>bin</id>

        <formats>
            <format>dir</format>
            <format>jar</format>
        </formats>

        <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
        <baseDirectory>basic-modules</baseDirectory>

        <dependencySets>
            <dependencySet>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*:payment-api</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </dependencySet>
        </dependencySets>

        <moduleSets>
            <moduleSet>

                <!-- Enable access to all projects in the current multimodule build! -->
                <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

                <!-- Now, select which projects to include in this module-set. -->
                <includes>
                    <include>*:paypal-payment</include>
                    <include>*:moneris-payment</include>
                </includes>

                <binaries>
                    <outputDirectory>${module.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
                    <outputFileNameMapping>${module.artifactId}.${module.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
                    <unpack>false</unpack>
                    <dependencySets>
                        <dependencySet>
                            <unpack>false</unpack>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>
                            <outputDirectory>${module.artifactId}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </dependencySet>
                    </dependencySets>
                </binaries>
            </moduleSet>

        </moduleSets>
    </assembly>
```

---

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>distro-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>basic-modules-${pom.version}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Is there a way you can test assemblies just running from the command line (mvn assembly:single -Ddescriptor=xxxxx), when I do that instead of running mvn package all sorts of strange results happen, that are not the same as when package phase is run, although the only difference is the assembly file

Comment: Seems dependencySet is just a set common to all artifacts included in the assembly, that goes for the root DependencySet and the modules DependencySet, and I didn't find a way to discriminate from where Dependencies comes from